# Two max widths in media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I saw someone use this in code and was wondering how this will work.  I've seen min-width and max-width but never this.  Does this mean only run when width is less than 460px, making the 768px max-width parameter irrelevant?

```
@media (max-width: 768px) and (max-width: 460px) {
 CSS goes here
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo?

Comment: It's not a special thing, it will take the smallest max width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a special thing, it will take the smallest max width

https://jsfiddle.net/

```css
.dog {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

.width {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  width: 460px;
}
@media (max-width: 460px) and (max-width: 768px) {

  .dog {
    background: red;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="width" width="460px">

</div>
<div class="dog">

</div>
```